# How can I use PHP to strip the last comma of mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, stack

I have a mysql_query where I need to strip the last comma behind the last item(s).

How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `items` (itemName, itemDescription  ) VALUES ("' . $form_input0 . '","' . $form_input1 . '",);');
```

The part that gives the "form_input" is what I am concerned with

```
"' . $form_input1 . '",
```

That trailing comma is what I need to strip ...

Some folks have suggested that I edit the question and include all of the code I am working with. Maybe it will help ...

```
<?php

$host = '%id=server%';
$user = '%id=username%';
$password = '%id=password%';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

$selected = mysql_select_db('%id=database%', $link);

if(!isset($_POST['text-input']))

?>



    <form method="post">
        %slice%
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    %[if !edit]%



<?php
%[repeat items]%
$form_input%id=repeatIndex% =  $_POST['element-%id=repeatIndex%'] ;

%[endrepeat]%

mysql_query('INSERT INTO `%id=table%` (%[repeat items]%  %[endif]%%html="Edit Me"%%[if !edit]% %[endrepeat]% ) VALUES (%[repeat items]%"' . $form_input%id=repeatIndex% . '",%[endrepeat]%);');

?>
%[endif]%
```

Comment: Why is the trailing comma there in the first place?  Better to treat the illness than the symptoms.

Comment: Indeed. SQL injection vulnerabilities, wrong quotes, let's not make it even worse by hacking at the string once it has already been created.

Comment: And stop using the damn mysql_* extention. It's deprecated. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @hookman - I appreciate you fervent evangelism for PDO, but I've not been able to wrap my head around it. I'm sure I'll take to it before too long though.

Comment: @KulerGary: MySQL extension has serious security issues and will eventually [be removed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) from PHP altogether. It's only beneficial to spend time learning some [other API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead of learning/getting used to the old one. Just sayin'

Comment: @KulerGary I still don't get it. If the code is *as is*, just do a backspace to get rid of the comma. If not, give us more detailed explanation and provide the code *as is*.

Comment: @norfavrell - Understood ... I know your right :)

Comment: @KulerGary: See my updated answer - hopefully it helps. Also removed downvote, the question is now *answerable* :) Would be nice if you included what framework/markup/parser/whatever you are using in tags or in the question itself - would help people who know it. One of the solutions could actually be based upon this - if you put this in tags people who know how to use your API would see the question and possibly provide a better answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **hookman** has rightly mentioned in comments [mysql extension is depreciated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) and should not be used.

**EDIT** Now that you code is edited. As you mentioned *I don't know the API* but I do know one possible solution.

- Assign your query to a variable.
- Replace the last part of the query so that the `,` is removed.

Try:

```
...
%[endrepeat]%

$query = 'INSERT INTO `%id=table%` (%[repeat items]%  %[endif]%%html="Edit Me"%%[if !edit]% %[endrepeat]% ) VALUES (%[repeat items]%"' . $form_input%id=repeatIndex% . '",%[endrepeat]%);';
$query = preg_replace('/,\);$/',');',$query);
mysql_query($query);

....
```

The `preg_replace` will simply edit your query, so that any string that has `,);` at the end of it, will be replaced with `);`. You can use that with other queries, just figure out how to transform them with RegEx.

I understand that your markup language (whatever it is that you use) has limitations that could prohibit you to do this utilizing it's standard functionality - in this case 'manually' (with regex or otherwise replace) editing the string is your only option (that or parsing it somehow).

Alternatively, this might work:

```
...

%[repeat items]%
$values = array(
    mysql_real_escape_string($form_input%id=repeatIndex%),
    mysql_real_escape_string($form_input%id=repeatIndex%)
);
%[endrepeat]%
$query = 'INSERT INTO `%id=table%` (%[repeat items]%  %[endif]%%html="Edit Me"%%[if !edit]% %[endrepeat]% ) VALUES (' . "'" . implode("','", $values) . "')";

...
```

Comment: The values are being created sort of "on the fly" and the commas are added automatically.

Comment: @KulerGary Explain this more detailed in your question. If the code in your question is as is - it looks like odd comma at the end, that's it.

Comment: I am working within an API that allows me to use a repeat variable. To allow users to add content to numerous columns in a mysql db I have to include a comma to separate column names. The problem this creates though is that there is a trailing comma ... which I hope to be able to remove.

Comment: @KulerGary: I suggest you edit your question and include the actual code that does that. As it stands I think this question is worded poorly, doesn't provide enough information for us to help you and is generally a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Unless you are familiar with the API I am working with then you will not understand how it works and how the code is produced which will only lead to circular questioning. But I will be happy to edit the question.

Comment: @KulerGary: Even if I don't understand the API, I have a better chance of figuring out how the code works (and ergo helping you) than not seeing the code at all ;)

Comment: @KulerGary Glad to be of help :)

Comment: If you're looking to maintain job security by introducing extremely complicated, unreadable code, then this approach would be the way to do it.

Comment: Both of these would fail any code review. What's happening is not obvious and where things are obscured, they almost always lead to trouble later. If it's not immediately apparent that your SQL is completely escaped, there's a risk it's not.

Comment: @tadman - Thanks for your concern but the problem is solved and mysql_ has been re-written using PHP PDO

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = str_replace(',);', ');', $sql);
```

But i would do it like this:

```
$values = array(
    $form_input0,
    $form_input1
);
$sql = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO `items` (itemName, itemDescription  ) VALUES ("%s")',
    implode('", "', $values)
);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Just a note: This will replace **all** occurrences of `,);` with `);`. Normally this will not be a problem, unless one of the `$form_input` variables contains `,);` (for whatever reason).

Comment: where would that need to go? Under the mysql_query? Before it?

Comment: @tadman - Agree ... the best solution was to re-write everything using more up-to-date methods